# How to convert Json to NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

I am developing one app in that i need to **convert Json data to NSDictionary**. I tried with some methods but i was unable to get dictionary in proper format. please can anyone suggest me. Below one is the Json format need to convert. Thanks in advance.

```
   {
        TUM =     {
            Category = "Social,games";
            CategoryStatus = "1,0";
            scs = 1;
            webdetail =(

                   {
                    app = facebook;
                    cat = Social;
                    days = "1,2,5";
                    daytime1 = "10:30-11:30,13:30-14:30,18:30-19:30";
                    daytime2 = "06:30-07:30,10:30-11:30,13:30-16:30";
                    daytime3 = "";
                    daytime4 = "";
                    daytime5 = "10:30-11:30,12:30-13:30";
                    daytime6 = "";
                    daytime7 = "";
                    lck = 2;
                },
                {
                    app = gmail;
                    cat = Social;
                    days = "1,5";
                    daytime1 = "10:30-11:30,18:30-19:30";
                    daytime2 = "";
                    daytime3 = "";
                    daytime4 = "";
                    daytime5 = "10:30-11:30,22:30-23:30";
                    daytime6 = "";
                    daytime7 = "";
                    lck = 2;
                }
            );
        };
    }
```

Comment: with downvote please comment answer

Comment: what you tried?Can you paste your code?

Comment: I voted to close because this isn't really a question. What "methods" did you try? What happened?

Comment: NSMutableDictionary *dJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];                                                              I used this method but i got this error --> [__NSDictionaryM bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa0aad0ffb0

Comment: That would have been useful information to include in your question. If you improve your question, people may reopen it for you.

Comment: The error suggests that `jsonData` isn't of type `NSData`. It's a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [NSJSONSerialization class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html) for parsing the JSON,it contains the logic to convert JSON data into NSArray or NSDictionary.

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

```
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *jsondictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                          options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers 
                                            error:&error];
```